# Can UITextField open voice input automatically?

Tags: ios, iphone

A simple question: if I open a keyboard, can it open in voice input automatically?

Thank you!

Comment: Currently that is not possible on iOS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextField begin dictation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503398/uitextfield-begin-dictation)

Comment: also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732252/how-do-i-programmatically-make-the-dictate-keyboard-key-be-pressed-in-ios-obj

Comment: You may look into some 3rd party libraries like:
[iSpeech](http://www.ispeech.org) or [SpeechKit](https://developer.nuance.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the response will be as simple as your question: No. Apple do not provide any way to do so.

The dictation process has to be launched by the user, not by the app.

Comment: i'm not happy, but the point is yours! thank U